# No page permissions in vaadin

Tags: security, vaadin, roles

I'm just getting started with vaadin and the roles don't work for me.
The class responsible for creating a new user is in /views/users/NewUser.java.
Everywhere I get this: [My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFrzl.png)

Link to repo on github: https://github.com/Rozumek29/plantseeker-panel

Answer (score 1):

I just ran you project (branch bb01af6) and it seems to work just fine. Since I did not have a MYSQL instance I used H2 instead. No other changes was done to run your project. As admin I was able to create a user without any issues.

Couple of recommendations. I would change New User route to use the layout class from `@Route("panel/users/add")` to `@Route(value="panel/users/add", layout = MainLayout.class)`. I would also use [Vaadin Binder](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/binding-data) instead of doing the binding myself. With a proper binder it is easy to use `.asRequired()` and `.withValidation(...)`.

Comment: You were right, I switched my database from MySQL to H2 and everything works fine. Do you know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I have not experienced what you are experiencing and it is some time since I played with MySQL. However this has nothing to do with Vaadin. I would try `spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or not specify any driver since I belive it is picked up by default as long as the dependency is in place.

Comment: I've already solved the problem. Mysql cannot handle UUID as a primary key. I changed id to long and it works perfect.

Comment: You can add the solution yourself. After a few days you can accept it.